# Leptonica fails all regression tests

Tags: build, tesseract, configure, leptonica

When I try installing building Leptonica 1.72 downloaded from their website: http://www.leptonica.com/download.html using the default installation route:

```
./configure
make
make check
```

I got 64/67 tests failed. I looked into this problem and installed some missing dependencies and when I tried building and checking again, 68/68 tests failed this time. Has anyone had the same problem? Where should I look to find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I needed root permissions to run the tests.

```
sudo make check
```

and all 68 tests passed. I'll look more into why I got the problem( maybe because I built with root permissions and then when I tested it without them, couldn't access the root-created test files and fails the tests. )

Tip: build without root permissions and only run with root permissions

```
make install
```